# Oracle Sor by for denormalized table

Tags: performance, sorting, oracle11g

Say we have a denormalized table where the row size is quite big.

When oracle is performing a sort by (in memory):
Is it loading in memory the whole row just to check a small column to order? or is it just loading in memory the ID and the column to sort?

Is the behavior when doing a sort in disk different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only sorts the required data, which includes the order-by columns and the data being projected.

If you select ten columns from a fifty column table, and sort by two columns not selected, then 12 columns are included in the sort area requirements.